# RewriteRule for http and https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On a Ubuntu system, I have drupal running on port 80. And I have other services running on port 8000(gunicorn), 8080(customServer), etc.

My objective is to direct all port 80 traffic to https and leave other services (8000,8080,etc) to http.

For now I have in 000-default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

  DocumentRoot /var/www
  <Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            DirectoryIndex index.html
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>

  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

But this directs everything (port 80,8000,8080,etc) to https.

What RewriteRule or RewriteCond can I use to direct http traffic for port 80 only to https and leave others alone?

I'm open to suggestions... even if RewriteRule is not the correct path. Thanks.

Comment: Tried the `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80`, and it made no changes. Still same behavior. Thanks.

Comment: You can get only the 80 port inside that VirtualHost.

Comment: @anubhava yes tried with cleared cache and I even installed a new browser to test it (just in case). Still didn't work. Thanks.